# How to evaluate my application design?

Tags: c#, architecture, xml-rpc

I am given a herculean task of architecture and design of a system. I am very comfortable with programming, not design. So, I have decided to beg some advice here about how/where to start my task. I have tried to put all the right questions(I think) in the picture below:

[image: Click above link to view bigger image]

[Actual Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1Aq.png)

So, I can answer one question among those: "Why XML-RPC?" Because, it's robust, well designed, industry standard way of communication (I read it in a IEEE paper).

Please answer any of the questions in the image.

P.S. I agree, asking for easy solution to all this(last question in image) is very lazy. But isn't that what one should do? Not solve anything that's been solved once?

EDIT:
The app has to basically provide a way for the remote users to interact with machine. One way to put it is, app should provide networking features to machine interaction api.

Comment: Sorry, this question is too vague. Maybe try again with a more specific question. You are asking "Is this the best design?", yet I have no idea what this program you are designing is supposed to do.

Comment: The app should basically provide a way for remote users to interact with a machine. One way to call it is, app should provide network callable machine interaction api. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I'm not really an expert in design, but I could see what you've presented here is very basic. Maybe you could try to add more details for example, what the machine do? Machine operation speed? and etc...

Comment: Why do you choose XML-RPC instead of WCF? imho a lot more devs are used to WCF.

Comment: @jgauffin Thanks for the suggestion. I will check out WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.

I think you'll need to do a little more research about exactly how you want to communicate between the server (machine computer) and the clients. One option might be two-way communications using MSMQ (message queue). Microsoft has a page about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752264.aspx

Here's how I see it possibly working. Each section is a separate project in your solution.

**Machine Computer (server) project (exe, console app?)**

- Contains a ServiceHost to accept API calls from the Client computers.
- When a new client computer connects, add to a list of clients to update.
- Remove the client from the list to update when they disconnect (or check if client is up before sending update communications).
- Accepts the API call, makes a call back to all client computers to give an in process status, and runs the request on the "Machine".
- When the "Machine" completes, makes a call to the client computers to give a complete status.

**Client Computer (client) project (exe, GUI app)**

- Contains a ServiceHost that accepts status updates from the Server.
- On start, send a notification(API) to the server that a new client is online.
- On quit, send a notification(API) to the server that the client is going offline.
- Provide a window showing the status and any other readings or information you have available, which will be provided from the Server.
- Give options to allow the user to send commands to the Server(API), which will be run on the Machine

**Contract project**

- Contains all the class objects that will be passed back and forth from client and server.
- Both client and server projects reference this project. Both will need to be able to use these classes for sending or receiving communications.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It will take some time for me to fully grasp what you said.

Comment: As jgauffin suggests I have chosen to go with WCF but itseems there too this knowledge of MSMQ can be used. Just putting the info here, so that someone might find it useful: **WCF is what I needed.**